# Change data type of column in multiple tables in Access with VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am fairly new to using VBA in MS Access and I am having trouble embedding SQL statements into VBA code. I have a database with almost 200 tables, and I would like to change the data type of one column (named lake) in each table to a "text" data type. I wrote the following code, but keep getting a syntax error for the ALTER TABLE statement.

```
Public Sub changeDataType()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim table As DAO.TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb

  For Each table In db.TableDefs
     DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE" & table.Name & "ALTER COLUMN [lake] TEXT(100);"
  Next

Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the syntax error?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this statement will not be correct:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE" & table.Name & "ALTER COLUMN [lake] TEXT(100);"
```

if, for instance "table.Name" = "myTable", the resulting statement will look like this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLEmyTableALTER COLUMN [lake] TEXT(100);"
```

try adding a space to separate the name, like this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE [" & table.Name & "] ALTER COLUMN [lake] TEXT(100);"
```

Comment: Good catch. You might want to go one step further and suggest `ALTER TABLE [" & table.Name & "] ..."` for added safety.

Comment: aha ... good as well ... I'll edit the answer to include ... thanks.

Comment: Thanks all. Gord, with your additional suggestion I got it to work...at least I think...Access is still running it. Thanks to both

Comment: should be able to ... what's the error message you are getting?